# Set DateTime to index and then sum over a day

Tags: pandas

i would like to change the index of my dataframe to datetime to sum the colum "Heizung" over a day.

But it dont work.

After i set the new index, i like to use resample to sum over a day.
Here is an extraction from my dataframe.

```
Nr;DatumZeit;Erdtemp;Heizung
0;25.04.21 12:58:42;21.8;1
1;25.04.21 12:58:54;21.8;1
2;25.04.21 12:59:06;21.9;1
3;25.04.21 12:59:18;21.9;1
4;25.04.21 12:59:29;21.9;1
5;25.04.21 12:59:41;22.0;1
6;25.04.21 12:59:53;22.0;1
7;25.04.21 13:00:05;22.1;1
8;25.04.21 13:00:16;22.1;0
9;25.04.21 13:00:28;22.1;0
10;25.04.21 13:00:40;22.1;0
11;25.04.21 13:00:52;22.2;0
12;25.04.21 13:01:03;22.2;0
13;25.04.21 13:01:15;22.2;1
14;25.04.21 13:01:27;22.2;1
15;25.04.21 13:01:39;22.3;1
16;25.04.21 13:01:50;22.3;1
17;25.04.21 13:02:02;22.4;1
18;25.04.21 13:02:14;22.4;1
19;25.04.21 13:02:26;22.4;0
20;25.04.21 13:02:37;22.4;1
21;25.04.21 13:02:49;22.4;0
22;25.04.21 13:03:01;22.4;0
23;25.04.21 13:03:13;22.5;0
24;25.04.21 13:03:25;22.4;0
```

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd


Tab = pd.read_csv('/home/kai/Dokumente/TempData', delimiter=';')

Tab1 = Tab[["DatumZeit","Erdtemp","Heizung"]].copy()

Tab1['DatumZeit'] = pd.to_datetime(Tab1['DatumZeit'])

Tab1.plot(x='DatumZeit', figsize=(20, 5),subplots=True)

#Tab1.index.to_datetime()

#Tab1.index = pd.to_datetime(Tab1.index)

Tab1.set_index('DatumZeit')

Tab.info()

Tab1.resample('D').sum()

print(Tab1.head(10))
```

Comment: you've thrown away result of setting the index...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how we can set index and create Timestamp object and then resample it for 'D' and sum a column over it.

```
Tab1['DatumZeit'] = pd.to_datetime(Tab1.DatumZeit)
Tab1 = Tab1.set_index('DatumZeit') ## missed here
Tab1.resample('D').Heizung.sum()
```

If we don't want to set index explicitly then other way to resample is pd.Grouper.

```
Tab1['DatumZeit'] = pd.to_datetime(Tab1.DatumZeit
Tab1.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='DatumZeit', freq='D')).Heizung.sum()
```

If we want output to be dataframe, then we can use to_frame method.

```
Tab1 = Tab1.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='DatumZeit', freq='D')).Heizung.sum().to_frame()
```

**Output**

```
            Heizung
DatumZeit   
2021-04-25  15
```

Answer (score 0):

Pivot tables to the rescue:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Tab1.pivot_table(index=["DatumZeit"], values=["Heizung"], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

If you need to do it with setting the index first, you need to use `inplace=True` on `set_index`

```py
Tab1.set_index("DatumZeit", inplace=True)
```

Just note if you do this way, you can't go back to a pivot table. In the end, it's whatever works best for you.

Comment: No problem. I prefer pivot_tables where I can. Just feels more natural. Nothing against groupby though. Sometimes, you have to use it.